# What would happen if I went over the wattage limit specified by my path lights?

Tags: electrical

I have a set of path lights that specify 5 watt maximum for replacement.  What happens if I put a higher wattage bulb in there?  Can it burn my system up or cause a fire?

Answer (score 7):

Yes and Yes. The maximum wattage is probably to prevent buildup of heat, and using a value over the limit could cause issues: melting the fixture, burning the bulb out, or potentially causing a fire. You will also cause a higher current to be flowing through the wiring, which could be an issue.

Note that the only important value is the *actual* wattage of the bulb, not the "watt-equivalent". E.g. if you switch to an LED bulb you may be able to get much more light while staying under 5 watts.